# method/function to generate the column names for a spreadsheet application similar to Excel

Tags: java

I'm trying to achieve the below output, e.g if I pass 5 to the function `columnNames`, it should print A, B, C, D, E and if pass 27 it should print A, B, C, D, E...AA, AB, AC etc.

I need to work with the below code snippet and I only need to work on the `columnNames` method.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Tester {
    static List<String> columnNames(int n) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int _columns = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine().trim());

        List<String> result = columnNames(_columns);

        System.out.println(String.join(", ", result));
    }
}
```

when I added this snippet to the `columnNames` method and passed 5 to the parameter, it only prints the column letter equivalent to the number I entered. However, I expected to see A,B,C,D,E.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (n > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        n--;
        char ch = (char) (n % 26 + 'A');
        n /= 26;
        sb.append(ch);
        result.add(sb.toString());
    }
}
sb.reverse();
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is the utility of `n /= 26;` because there lays your problem. When it's used, `n` becomes littler than `i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to figure it out with the code below. Thanks to those who have helped in a way.

```
static List<String> columnNames(int n) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    String alphabets[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        int index = j/26;   
            char ch = (char) (j % 26 + 'A');               
          sb.append(ch);
          String item = "";
          if(index > 0) {
              item += alphabets[index-1];
          }
          item += alphabets[j % 26];
          result.add(item);
    }
    sb.reverse();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code produces what you want:

```
StringBuilder sb;

char current = 'A';

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // new StringBuilder for every String
    sb = new StringBuilder();

    // If 'i' exceeds letters, use the ones you have already added to your List
    if (i > 25)
        sb.append(result.get(i - 26));

    // Append current character
    sb.append(current);

    // Add it to your List
    result.add(sb.toString());

    // Get the next letter while making sure it will not surpass 'Z'
    if (current == 'Z')
        current = 'A';
    else
        current = (char) (current + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks thunder197. Your answer seem work to an extent but not completely. When i entered 28 as the value of the parameter, I got the following output
A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, AA, BB instead of this
A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, AA, AB

Comment: @brownwood But according to your question you want exactly that 
"it should print A, B, C, D, E and if pass 27 it should print A, B, C, D, E...AA, BB, CC etc"

Comment: @brownwood You said you want AA,BB not AA,AB

Comment: My bad. @thunder197

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you want.

```
static List<String> columnNames(int n) 
{
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    String[] alphs = new String[] {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N",
            "O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};



    if(n>-1 && n<27)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
        {
            result.add(alphs[i]);
        }

    }
    else
    {

        for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
        {
            result.add(alphs[i]);   
            n--;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<26; j++)
            {
                if(n!=0)
                {
                    result.add(result.get(i).concat(alphs[j]));
                    n--;
                }
                else
                {
                    return result;
                }

            }

        }

    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the code fails to exit and run for n > 702

Java Doodle link [Work upto 'ZZ' sequence](http://jdoodle.com/a/QGE)

Answer (score 0):

here you go..

```
private static final List<String> englishCapitalAlphabet = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z");

private static int findClosestPowerOfXApprochingNFromTheHigherEnd(int x, int n) {
    int power = 1;
    while (Math.pow(x, power) < n) {
        power += 1;
    }
    return power;
}

private static String generatePermutativeLabel(List<String> primitives, int serialNumber) {
    int places = findClosestPowerOfXApprochingNFromTheHigherEnd(primitives.size(), serialNumber);
    String label = "";
    for (int i = (places - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        label += primitives.get((int) Math.floor((serialNumber / Math.pow(primitives.size(), i)) - 1));
        serialNumber %= Math.pow(primitives.size(), i);
    }
    return label;
}

public static String generatePermutativeLabelWithCapitalAlphabets(int serialNumber) {
    return generatePermutativeLabel(englishCapitalAlphabet, serialNumber);
}
```

unfortunately the above code does not account for the fact that these labels have no representation of zero, which has been corrected in the below code and it will work for arbitrarily long labels

```
    /* Assumes the labels represent a Natural Number Sequence.
 * The Set of Characters involed in the labelling are assumed to have an order and they are pre-defined,
 * and they are incrementally numbered in that order start from the number one.
 * The right most character's (RMC) value is multiplied by,
 * the total count of the valid characters (TC) raised to the power zero,
 * the value of next character to the RMC is multiplied by TC raised to the power one and so on.
 * Example: for the set (A, B, C):
 *     TC is 3
 *     the label "A" has the value 1
 *     the label "C" has the value 3
 *     the label "ACBA" has the value 1321 (1 * 3^3 + 3 * 3^2 + 2 * 3^1 + 1 * 3^0)
 */

private static final List<String> englishCapitalAlphabet = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z");

private static int findClosestPowerOfXApprochingNFromTheHigherEnd(int x, int n) {
    int power = 1;
    while (Math.pow(x, power) < n) {
        power += 1;
    }
    return power;
}

/* Returns the number sequence without multiplying it with the positional coefficient
 */
private static List<Integer> generatePermutativeSequence(int totalCount, int number) {
    int places = findClosestPowerOfXApprochingNFromTheHigherEnd(totalCount, number);
    List<Integer> bareValues = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(places, 0));
    for (int i = (places - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        bareValues.set(i, (int) Math.floor(number / Math.pow(totalCount, i)));

        number %= Math.pow(totalCount, i);
        if (number == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return bareValues;
}

/* Assumes that the Left Most Value will not needed to be borrowed from.
 * Assumes that all zero sequences will be optionally preceded (in the left most side) by a sequence of mixed zeros and ones,
 * and immediately preceded by a number greater than one.
 * Assumes Whole Numbers only.
 */
private static List<Integer> rearrangeToEliminateZeros(int totalCount, List<Integer> bareValues) {
    if (!bareValues.contains(0)) {
        return bareValues;
    }

    // finding the sequence to be rearranged
    int lastZeroIndex = bareValues.lastIndexOf(0);
    int lastNonZeroOrOneIndex = lastZeroIndex;
    while (bareValues.get(lastNonZeroOrOneIndex).equals(0) || bareValues.get(lastNonZeroOrOneIndex).equals(1)) {
        lastNonZeroOrOneIndex += 1;
    }

    // rearranging
    for (int i = lastNonZeroOrOneIndex; i > lastZeroIndex; i--) {
        bareValues.set(i, bareValues.get(i) - 1);
        bareValues.set(i - 1, bareValues.get(i - 1) + totalCount);
    }

    return rearrangeToEliminateZeros(totalCount, bareValues);
}

public static String generatePermutativeLabel(List<String> primitives, int serialNumber) {
    if (serialNumber < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only Natural Numbers can be labeled.");
    }

    int totalCount = primitives.size();
    if (totalCount < 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Total count cannot be lesser than two.");
    }

    List<Integer> bareValues = rearrangeToEliminateZeros(totalCount, generatePermutativeSequence(totalCount, serialNumber));
    Collections.reverse(bareValues);
    String label = "";
    for (Integer i : bareValues) {
        label += primitives.get(i - 1);
    }
    return label;
}

public static String generatePermutativeLabelWithCapitalAlphabets(int serialNumber) {
    return generatePermutativeLabel(englishCapitalAlphabet, serialNumber);
}
```